# Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'top') on Scrolling Website

Tags: javascript

I have JS Error when Scrolling Website.
Here is Code:

```
$(window).scroll(() => {
    topOfFooter = $('.footer-sgm-main').position().top;
    scrollDistanceFromTopOfDoc = $(document).scrollTop() + 1350;
    scrollDistanceFromTopOfFooter = scrollDistanceFromTopOfDoc - topOfFooter;
    if (scrollDistanceFromTopOfDoc > topOfFooter) {
        $('.edc_course_show_fixed').css('opacity', 0);
    } else {
        $('.edc_course_show_fixed').css('opacity', 1);
    }
});
```

Error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'top')

Comment: `position()` ever returns undefined?? by the way you should include the html

Comment: `position()` is returning `undefined`, so `top` cannot be read as a property.  Check usage to determine why `position` would return `undefined`.